# Embedding a GLFW window inside windows forms

Tags: c++, opengl, user-interface, glfw

I'm making an editor for 3d worlds in opengl using the windows forms UI. I'm developing on visual studio 2012 express and i would like to embed a GLFW window/context inside a windows form. just like done in this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16051/Creating-an-OpenGL-view-on-a-Windows-Form except working. And with GLFW for opengl context.

Is this possible? should i use Qt instead? and how would i got about doing this? I'm not bound to using windows forms i just need a simple good-looking functional UI for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That are three different frameworks (Windows Forms, GLFW, Qt) which can all do the same thing, i.e. creating a window and an OpenGL context in it.

See [here](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html) for an easy example how to create a window with OpenGL context with GLFW.

Or see [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/hellogl.html) for the Qt example.

So, you have to choose between one of them. GLFW and Qt have the advantages that your code will also work on MacOSX and on Linux; with some work even on iPhone.

---

If you want to do the window creation and event handling and other stuff with GLFW but the GUI still with Qt, there is some way to do offline drawing (some ref [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt-Platform-Abstraction) or [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Getting_Started_With_Lighthouse) or [here](http://qt-project.org/videos/watch/qpa-the-qt-platform-abstraction)) the Qt widgets and then draw it onto some OpenGL texture. Or you might also be able to directly draw them via OpenGL (not exactly sure).

Comment: I want to use GLFW for opengl, and qt for GUI. is that possible?

Comment: I extended my answer. Is that the way you want to do it?

Comment: the links are broken and out of date , what is the status of those things today with Qt 5.4?