# embed window(glfwCreateWindow) as child to C++ MFC parent form

Tags: opengl, visual-c++, mfc, glfw

Please refer this link

[Embedding a GLFW window inside windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19396560/3679600)

How can the same achieved by using VC++ to embed glfw window to Parent form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

1. Call `glfwWindowHint()` to set `GLFW_DECORATED` and `GLFW_VISIBLE` to `false`.
2. Call `glfwCreateWindow()`.
3. Call `glfwGetWin32Window()` to get the native handle of the OpenGL window.
4. Call `SetParent()` to set your form as the new parent of the OpenGL window.
5. Call `GetWindowLong()` / `SetWindowLong()` to remove the `WS_POPUP` and add the `WS_CHILDWINDOW` style for the OpenGL window.
6. Call `ShowWindow()` to finally make the OpenGL window visible.

I got this from [github.com/Chronial/foo_chronflow :: EngineWindow.cpp](https://github.com/Chronial/foo_chronflow/blob/3cd1599f627710af910f03a879450edd71b2ac2f/EngineWindow.cpp#L49).

You might also call `SetWindowPos()` to adjust the position of the OpenGL window within your form.

Comment: I will implement your method and update you.This is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Getting error message "glfwGetWin32Window()" not defined.I have tried including #include <glfw3native.h> after #include <glfw3.h> but no luck. Are there any particular macros that I need to define?

Comment: I have included #define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WGL 
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_WIN32 and seems ok now

Comment: @LittleQuest Great. If this answer works for you, please accept it by clicking the check mark button.

Comment: :Sure.I am sure this method will work but glfwGetWin32Window is returning NULL.Trying to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: read glfw3native.h. you probably have to recompile the library with the update define if you aren't directly using its source code.

Answer (score 1):

The link in zett42's post is dead, so here's a more complete snippet

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);

GLFWwindow* pWindow = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, "", NULL, NULL);

HWND hwNative = glfwGetWin32Window(m_pWindow);

SetParent(hwNative, hwParentWindow);

long style = GetWindowLong(hwNative, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~WS_POPUP; // remove popup style
style |= WS_CHILDWINDOW; // add childwindow style
SetWindowLong(hwNative, GWL_STYLE, style);

... any other initialisation code (e.g enable/disable gl features) ...

ShowWindow(hwNative, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed the link too.