# How do I embed a GLFW3 window into a WPF form?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, glfw

I have a GLFW3 OpenGL project written in C++. I was looking to create a modern GUI to go with it. I have limited experience with XAML and windows WPF but it is intuitive to work with so I really want this to work.

I found 'WpfUnmanagedOpenGL' template from Github https://github.com/kopaka1822/WpfUnmanagedOpenGL and it runs great with a C++ DLL communicating with the Csharp OpenGL host window that is already working within the form using GLAD, not GLFW.

I managed to create a GLFW window with my existing code and it displays as a second popup window when the WPF form is compiled and run. See: [image]

How can I embed this correctly?

I found this question on StackOverflow: [embed window(glfwCreateWindow) as child to C++ MFC parent form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46152212/embed-windowglfwcreatewindow-as-child-to-c-mfc-parent-form) .

Essentially it says I can set the GLFW window to be a child window of the WPF form. However I cannot get the WPF parent window handle to set it all up.

PLEASE help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try to do the opposite. Rather than embedding your Win32 app inside your WPF form, embed your WPF form within your Win32 app instead.

Official docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-hosting-wpf-content-in-win32?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

A really neat tutorial:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5253279/Create-An-Awesome-WPF-UI-for-Your-Cplusplus-QT-App

This is for the legacy .NET Framework though. I have no clue if the same technique can be applied in the new .NET Core framework though.